# Mathematical functions for SIMD registers

Tags: gcc, simd, avx

According to https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec GCC has vector implementation of math functions. They can be used by compiler for optimizations, it can be seen in this example: https://godbolt.org/g/IcxtVi, compiler uses some mangled sine function and operates on 4 doubles at a time

I know that there are SIMD math libraries that can be used if I need math functions, but I am still interested is there a way to manually call vectorized math functions that already exist in GCC on `__m256d` variable with some kind of intrinsic or in any other way?

Comment: Those are the same SIMD instructions that get generated when the compiler vectorises the the code. So the easiest to use compiler generated vectorisation "-O3". The added benefit is that wen SSE goes to SSE4, or AVX512 then you compile and get new SIMD instructions. 10 years ago when this was all cutting edge it made sense to manually do it, but it may not make sense now, because you can get the same code most of the time. So save the heavy lifting for areas where it will not auto vectorise and use it sparingly there... That is my recommendation.

Comment: @Holmz: Compilers still don't auto-vectorize (well or at all) when shuffling is needed.  It would be useful to be able to call glibc's vectorized `sinf()` function manually with a `__m256` arg, now that such things apparently exist.  Recommending that people don't manually vectorize is good in theory, but not in practice.

Comment: @PeterCordes - More along the lines of only using SSE when the compiler cannot do it. I did not catch the shuffling mention or what that implies. But they do mention wanting to do it manually. I was thinking of "#pragma omp simd".

Comment: @Holmz: you usually need to do it manually when vectorizing requires clever use of `_mm256_shuffle_ps` or something.  https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/.

Answer (score 10):

Libmvec is a x86_64 glibc library with SSE4, AVX, AVX2, and AVX-512 vectorized functions for 
`cos`, `exp`, `log`, `sin`, `pow`, and `sincos`, in single precision and double precision.
The accuracy of these functions is 4-ulp maximum relative error.

Usually gcc inserts calls to Libmvec functions, such as `_ZGVdN4v_cos`,
while it is auto-vectorizing scalar code, for example with `-ffast-math` or 
`#pragma omp simd`. However, these vector functions are also suitable for 
manually vectorizing C code. 
Unfortunately the [Libmvec document](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec) 
does not give many examples that explain how to use these functions for 
manually vectorizing C code.

To use the Libmvec functions one has to include the function declarations
and link the code with the `-lm` (link with math library) option.
The linker doesn't need `-lmvec`, linking the standard math library `-lm` is 
sufficient for not static builds, see [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8333).
The `-ffast-math` compiler option is not necesary.

The following example shows how to call the AVX2 vectorized functions.
This example runs successful on a standard Ubuntu 18.04 system (glibc version 2.27).

```c
/* gcc -Wall -O3 -m64 -march=skylake libmvec_ex.c -lm */ 
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE      /* These two lines are optional. They are only needed to use the scalar */
#include <math.h>        /* functions sin, exp, sincos,...                                       */

__m256d _ZGVdN4v_cos(__m256d x);                    
__m256d _ZGVdN4v_exp(__m256d x);                    
__m256d _ZGVdN4v_log(__m256d x);                    
__m256d _ZGVdN4v_sin(__m256d x);                    
__m256d _ZGVdN4vv_pow(__m256d x, __m256d y); 
void    _ZGVdN4vvv_sincos(__m256d x, __m256i ptrs, __m256i ptrc);

__m256  _ZGVdN8v_cosf(__m256 x);            
__m256  _ZGVdN8v_expf(__m256 x);            
__m256  _ZGVdN8v_logf(__m256 x);            
__m256  _ZGVdN8v_sinf(__m256 x);            
__m256  _ZGVdN8vv_powf(__m256 x, __m256 y); 
void    _ZGVdN8vvv_sincosf(__m256 x, __m256i ptrs_lo, __m256i ptrs_hi, __m256i ptrc_lo, __m256i ptrc_hi);

int mm256_print_pd(__m256d x);
int mm256_print_ps(__m256 x);

int main()
{
  __m256d x, y, z;
  __m256 xf, yf, zf;
  double z_s[4], z_c[4];          /* sincos output                              */
  float zf_s[8], zf_c[8];         /* sincosf output                             */
  __m256i ptrs, ptrc;             /* Pointers to the elements of z_s and z_c    */ 
  __m256i ptrs_lo, ptrs_hi, ptrc_lo, ptrc_hi;

  x = _mm256_set_pd (0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01);
  y = _mm256_set_pd (2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5);
  xf = _mm256_set_ps (0.08f, 0.07f, 0.06f, 0.05f, 0.04f, 0.03f, 0.02f, 0.01f);
  yf = _mm256_set_ps (4.0f, 3.5f, 3.0f, 2.5f, 2.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f);

  printf("AVX2 Double precision examples\n");
                             printf("x             "); mm256_print_pd(x);
                             printf("y             "); mm256_print_pd(y);
  z =_ZGVdN4v_cos(x);        printf("cos(x)        "); mm256_print_pd(z);
  z =_ZGVdN4v_exp(x);        printf("exp(x)        "); mm256_print_pd(z);
  z =_ZGVdN4v_log(x);        printf("log(x)        "); mm256_print_pd(z);
  z =_ZGVdN4v_sin(x);        printf("sin(x)        "); mm256_print_pd(z);
  z =_ZGVdN4vv_pow(x, y);    printf("pow(x,y)      "); mm256_print_pd(z);

  ptrs = _mm256_set_epi64x((uint64_t)&z_s[3],(uint64_t)&z_s[2],(uint64_t)&z_s[1],(uint64_t)&z_s[0]);
  ptrc = _mm256_set_epi64x((uint64_t)&z_c[3],(uint64_t)&z_c[2],(uint64_t)&z_c[1],(uint64_t)&z_c[0]);
/* Alternative: ptrs = _mm256_add_epi64(_mm256_set1_epi64x((uint64_t)&z_s[0]),_mm256_set_epi64x(24,16,8,0));  */
/* This might be more efficient if the destination addresses are contiguous in memory.                        */
  _ZGVdN4vvv_sincos(x, ptrs, ptrc);                                 /* The results of _ZGVdN4vvv_sincos are scattered into the adresses in ptrs and ptrc */ 
  printf("sincos cos(x) %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f  \n", z_c[3], z_c[2], z_c[1], z_c[0]);
  printf("sincos sin(x) %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f\n\n", z_s[3], z_s[2], z_s[1], z_s[0]);

  printf("AVX2 Single precision examples\n");
                             printf("x             "); mm256_print_ps(xf);
                             printf("y             "); mm256_print_ps(yf);
  zf =_ZGVdN8v_cosf(xf);     printf("cosf(x)       "); mm256_print_ps(zf);
  zf =_ZGVdN8v_expf(xf);     printf("expf(x)       "); mm256_print_ps(zf);
  zf =_ZGVdN8v_logf(xf);     printf("logf(x)       "); mm256_print_ps(zf);
  zf =_ZGVdN8v_sinf(xf);     printf("sinf(x)       "); mm256_print_ps(zf);
  zf =_ZGVdN8vv_powf(xf, yf);printf("powf(x,y)     "); mm256_print_ps(zf);

  ptrs_lo = _mm256_set_epi64x((uint64_t)&zf_s[3],(uint64_t)&zf_s[2],(uint64_t)&zf_s[1],(uint64_t)&zf_s[0]);
  ptrs_hi = _mm256_set_epi64x((uint64_t)&zf_s[7],(uint64_t)&zf_s[6],(uint64_t)&zf_s[5],(uint64_t)&zf_s[4]);
  ptrc_lo = _mm256_set_epi64x((uint64_t)&zf_c[3],(uint64_t)&zf_c[2],(uint64_t)&zf_c[1],(uint64_t)&zf_c[0]);
  ptrc_hi = _mm256_set_epi64x((uint64_t)&zf_c[7],(uint64_t)&zf_c[6],(uint64_t)&zf_c[5],(uint64_t)&zf_c[4]);
  _ZGVdN8vvv_sincosf(xf, ptrs_lo, ptrs_hi, ptrc_lo, ptrc_hi);       /* The results of _ZGVdN8vvv_sincosf are scattered to the adresses in ptrs_lo, ptrs_hi, ptrc_lo, and ptrc_hi */ 
  printf("sincosf cos(x)%12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f \n", 
           zf_c[7], zf_c[6], zf_c[5], zf_c[4], zf_c[3], zf_c[2], zf_c[1], zf_c[0]);
  printf("sincosf sin(x)%12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f  \n",
           zf_s[7], zf_s[6], zf_s[5], zf_s[4], zf_s[3], zf_s[2], zf_s[1], zf_s[0]);

  return 0;
}


__attribute__ ((noinline)) int mm256_print_pd(__m256d x){
    double vec_x[4];
    _mm256_storeu_pd(vec_x,x);
    printf("%12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f  \n", vec_x[3], vec_x[2], vec_x[1], vec_x[0]);
    return 0;
}


__attribute__ ((noinline)) int mm256_print_ps(__m256 x){
    float vec_x[8];
    _mm256_storeu_ps(vec_x,x);
    printf("%12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f \n", vec_x[7], vec_x[6], vec_x[5], vec_x[4],
                     vec_x[3], vec_x[2], vec_x[1], vec_x[0]);
    return 0;
}
/*
```

The output is as expected:

```
$ ./a.out
AVX2 Double precision examples
x               0.04000000   0.03000000   0.02000000   0.01000000  
y               2.00000000   1.50000000   1.00000000   0.50000000  
cos(x)          0.99920011   0.99955003   0.99980001   0.99995000  
exp(x)          1.04081077   1.03045453   1.02020134   1.01005017  
log(x)         -3.21887582  -3.50655790  -3.91202301  -4.60517019  
sin(x)          0.03998933   0.02999550   0.01999867   0.00999983  
pow(x,y)        0.00160000   0.00519615   0.02000000   0.10000000  
sincos cos(x)   0.99920011   0.99955003   0.99980001   0.99995000  
sincos sin(x)   0.03998933   0.02999550   0.01999867   0.00999983

AVX2 Single precision examples
x               0.08000000   0.07000000   0.06000000   0.05000000   0.04000000   0.03000000   0.02000000   0.01000000 
y               4.00000000   3.50000000   3.00000000   2.50000000   2.00000000   1.50000000   1.00000000   0.50000000 
cosf(x)         0.99680173   0.99755102   0.99820060   0.99875027   0.99920011   0.99955004   0.99979997   0.99995005 
expf(x)         1.08328700   1.07250810   1.06183648   1.05127108   1.04081070   1.03045452   1.02020133   1.01005018 
logf(x)        -2.52572870  -2.65926003  -2.81341076  -2.99573231  -3.21887589  -3.50655794  -3.91202307  -4.60517025 
sinf(x)         0.07991469   0.06994285   0.05996400   0.04997917   0.03998933   0.02999550   0.01999867   0.00999983 
powf(x,y)       0.00004096   0.00009075   0.00021600   0.00055902   0.00160000   0.00519615   0.02000000   0.10000000 
sincosf cos(x)  0.99680173   0.99755102   0.99820060   0.99875027   0.99920011   0.99955004   0.99979997   0.99995005 
sincosf sin(x)  0.07991469   0.06994285   0.05996400   0.04997917   0.03998933   0.02999550   0.01999867   0.00999983
```

Note that the vectorized `sincos` functions scatters the results to 4 (double) or 
8 (float), not necessarily contiguous, memory locations.

**Function declarations for SSE4, AVX, and AVX2, with Intel SVML alternative.**

The code block below shows the function declaration for many different cases,
and the corresponding SVML function from Intel's SVML library.
Somehow I couldn't find these declarations, with the right parameter lists,
on the internet.

```c
/* Double precision Libmvec                        Intel SVML function                     */

/* SSE4                                                                                    */
__m128d _ZGVbN2v_cos(__m128d x);               /*  _mm_cos_pd(x)                           */
__m128d _ZGVbN2v_exp(__m128d x);               /*  _mm_exp_pd(x)                           */ 
__m128d _ZGVbN2v_log(__m128d x);               /*  _mm_log_pd(x)                           */
__m128d _ZGVbN2v_sin(__m128d x);               /*  _mm_sin_pd(x)                           */ 
__m128d _ZGVbN2vv_pow(__m128d x, __m128d y);   /*  _mm_pow_pd(x, y)                        */
void    _ZGVbN2vvv_sincos(__m128d x, __m128i ptrs, __m128i ptrc);    /* _mm_sincos_pd      */
/* AVX                                                                                     */
__m256d _ZGVcN4v_cos(__m256d x);               /*  _mm256_cos_pd(x)                        */
__m256d _ZGVcN4v_exp(__m256d x);               /*  _mm256_exp_pd(x)                        */ 
__m256d _ZGVcN4v_log(__m256d x);               /*  _mm256_log_pd(x)                        */
__m256d _ZGVcN4v_sin(__m256d x);               /*  _mm256_sin_pd(x)                        */ 
__m256d _ZGVcN4vv_pow(__m256d x, __m256d y);   /*  _mm256_pow_pd(x, y)                     */ 
void    _ZGVcN4vvv_sincos(__m256d x, __m256i ptrs, __m256i ptrc);    /* _mm256_sincos_pd   */
/* AVX2                                                                                    */
__m256d _ZGVdN4v_cos(__m256d x);               /*  _mm256_cos_pd(x)                        */
__m256d _ZGVdN4v_exp(__m256d x);               /*  _mm256_exp_pd(x)                        */ 
__m256d _ZGVdN4v_log(__m256d x);               /*  _mm256_log_pd(x)                        */
__m256d _ZGVdN4v_sin(__m256d x);               /*  _mm256_sin_pd(x)                        */ 
__m256d _ZGVdN4vv_pow(__m256d x, __m256d y);   /*  _mm256_pow_pd(x, y)                     */
void    _ZGVdN4vvv_sincos(__m256d x, __m256i ptrs, __m256i ptrc);    /* _mm256_sincos_pd   */


/* Single precision Libmvec                       Intel SVML function                      */

/* SSE4                                                                                    */
__m128  _ZGVbN4v_cosf(__m128 x);               /* _mm_cos_ps(x)                            */
__m128  _ZGVbN4v_expf(__m128 x);               /* _mm_exp_ps(x)                            */ 
__m128  _ZGVbN4v_logf(__m128 x);               /* _mm_log_ps(x)                            */
__m128  _ZGVbN4v_sinf(__m128 x);               /* _mm_sin_ps(x)                            */ 
__m128  _ZGVbN4vv_powf(__m128 x, __m128 y);    /* _mm_pow_ps(x, y) */ 
void    _ZGVbN4vvv_sincosf(__m128 x, __m128i ptrs_lo, __m128i ptrs_hi, __m128i ptrc_lo, __m128i ptrc_hi);      /* _mm_sincos_ps   */
/* AVX                                                                                     */
__m256  _ZGVcN8v_cosf(__m256 x);               /* _mm256_cos_ps(x)                         */
__m256  _ZGVcN8v_expf(__m256 x);               /* _mm256_exp_ps(x)                         */ 
__m256  _ZGVcN8v_logf(__m256 x);               /* _mm256_log_ps(x)                         */
__m256  _ZGVcN8v_sinf(__m256 x);               /* _mm256_sin_ps(x)                         */ 
__m256  _ZGVcN8vv_powf(__m256 x, __m256 y);    /* _mm256_pow_ps(x, y)                      */ 
void    _ZGVcN8vvv_sincosf(__m256 x, __m256i ptrs_lo, __m256i ptrs_hi, __m256i ptrc_lo, __m256i ptrc_hi);      /* _mm256_sincos_ps   */
/* AVX2                                                                                    */
__m256  _ZGVdN8v_cosf(__m256 x);               /* _mm256_cos_ps(x)                         */
__m256  _ZGVdN8v_expf(__m256 x);               /* _mm256_exp_ps(x)                         */ 
__m256  _ZGVdN8v_logf(__m256 x);               /* _mm256_log_ps(x)                         */
__m256  _ZGVdN8v_sinf(__m256 x);               /* _mm256_sin_ps(x)                         */ 
__m256  _ZGVdN8vv_powf(__m256 x, __m256 y);    /* _mm256_pow_ps(x, y)                      */
void    _ZGVdN8vvv_sincosf(__m256 x, __m256i ptrs_lo, __m256i ptrs_hi, __m256i ptrc_lo, __m256i ptrc_hi);      /* _mm256_sincos_ps   */

/* Note that I only tested the AVX2 function declarations.                                 */
/* AVX-512: _ZGVeN16v_cosf, _ZGVeN8v_cos etc.                                              */
```

**Useful links:**

https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec

https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=VectorABI.txt

https://github.com/sgallagher/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libmvec.abilist

https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/b4/c8/Intel-Vector-Function-ABI.pdf