Rust auto vectorization of exp function
I am trying to get some good codegen for a Rust binary in x64 but it seems very hard to get simd operations for exp.
I have a simplified code example: https://godbolt.org/z/4MY34T1zj
The code should be easy to vectorize but I get scalar calls to glibc exp.
I can't show with godbold, but the same happens when I use rust libm and also link time optimizations.
What are the strategies to get vectorized codegen for floating point functions like exp, log, etc?
Edit:
The LLVM-IR looks to me (who cannot really read llvm-ir) like it has all it needs to vectorize:
vector.body:
  %index = phi i64 [ 0, %vector.ph ], [ %index.next, %vector.body ]
  %0 = getelementptr inbounds [0 x double], ptr %x.0, i64 0, i64 %index
  %wide.load = load <4 x double>, ptr %0, align 8
  %1 = tail call <4 x double> @llvm.exp.v4f64(<4 x double> %wide.load)
  store <4 x double> %1, ptr %0, align 8
  %index.next = add nuw i64 %index, 4
  %2 = icmp eq i64 %index.next, %n.vec
  br i1 %2, label %middle.block, label %vector.body

So it seems to be a limitation of llvm
This seems relevant: https://reviews.llvm.org/D95373

Don't know if you can do this in Rust, but you may find this helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336648/call-libmvec-functions-manually-on-m128-vectors

Ok, but why can't you rewrite in assembly yourself if you absolutely need that performance?

@freakish Of course this is possible, but takes quite a bit of time and is error prone.
I could also call simd functions explicitly but this would require me to vectorize manually, even though it is such a trivial case.
The point is that this is an easy optimization for a compiler to do and I am asking how to encourage it to do it
